# How to avoid resizing UITextView content when applying a transform

Tags: swift, uitextview

I'm making a little notes app in which i've added a textView inside each cell, when selecting a cell it scales itself to certain size so the textView is scaled too. Everything is fine except that the text inside the textView is also scaled and looks pretty bad.
Does anyone know how to prevent the text from resizing or how can i handle this issue?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! collectionViewCell3
    cell.clipsToBounds = false
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    noteTextView[indexPath.item].frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: cell.frame.width - 20, height: cell.frame.height - 20)
    noteTextView[indexPath.item].delegate = self
    noteTextView[indexPath.item].textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 10
    noteTextView[indexPath.item].isScrollEnabled = false
    noteTextView[indexPath.item].font = UIFont(name: "Noteworthy-Light", size: 12)
    noteTextView[indexPath.item].text = items[indexPath.item]
    cell.contentView.addSubview(noteTextView[indexPath.item])
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    index = indexPath
    notasCollectionView.isScrollEnabled = false
    let cell = notasCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    let desiredPointY = notasCollectionView.contentOffset.y + 350
    let desiredPointX = notasCollectionView.center.x
    let differenceX = desiredPointX - cell!.frame.midX
    let differenceY = desiredPointY - cell!.frame.mid
    let differenceHeight = 354 / (cell?.frame.height)!
    var tt = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.89304813, y: differenceHeight)
    tt = tt.concatenating(CGAffineTransform(translationX: differenceX, y: differenceY))
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0.0, animations: {
        self.notasCollectionView.bringSubviewToFront(cell!)
        cell!.transform = tt
    }, completion: { _ in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
            cell?.layer.cornerRadius = 0
        }
    })
}
```

Here are the screenshots:

[![Screenshot 1][1]][1]    [![Screenshot 2][2]][2]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYURo.png    [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbDND.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are increasing the size of the text view but the font size is the same.

So you need to change the font size according to your scaling multiplier.

Comment: I've tried that but still looks stretched because of the scaling, looks like it's pixelated.

Comment: I've done something like this and it works for me, please edit the question with the changes u did